# How to Restore DataBase Backup that found in another server?

Tags: sql-server, backup

using sqlServer 2012 ..I have abackup File (MyDataBase.Bak) found in server Ip=(134.122.123:4454) .. and I want to restore this backup to another server .. the same dataBase in another server (MyDataBase) ,, server IP (134.122.124:4455) .. How can I do that , how can I restore database Found in another server ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to restore your backup file in different server then other option is generate script and just you have to run on different server.

Right click database → Tasks → Generate Scripts → Select your table → Click on Advance button → Types of Data to script - Select Schema and Data → Click on Next button.

Now run your generated script on different server.

Comment: NO , I want to make bakeup and restore to multiple databases and to make it run automatically